# Can I debug a workflow on Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

I have a question about Sharepoint Online debugging.

I've created a Sharepoint app with Visual 2015, destined to sharepoint-online and it's sharepoint hosted. Inside, I have a very simple workflow.

When I try to debug it, the following message appears:

[image: error dialog]

Is it necessary to have an Azure account to debug a workflow? Are there any other options in workflow development?

If it helps, the deployment environment is Office 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to have an Azure account to debug SharePoint Online/Office 365 workflows. This is because you can't access certain components that are used for debugging a local SharePoint workflow. Instead Microsoft created the Relay Service component of the Microsoft Azure Service Bus. (A secure component that they charge for hosting)

Before this component was released it does't appear debugging was possible. (See article below)

[Debugging Workflows In SharePoint 2013 Online using Azure](http://jeremysublett.blogspot.ca/2014/03/debugging-workflows-in-sharepoint-2013.html).

If you have an MSDN subscription or work for a Microsoft partner organization you should receive some free access to Azure.

[Workflow debugging for SharePoint Online requires a Windows Azure Service Bus connection](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0a461221-aca3-42ff-a7a0-8cb14637304a/workflow-debugging-for-sharepoint-online-requires-a-windows-azure-service-bus-connection?forum=sharepointgeneral).

Answer (score 0):

To enable remote debugging:

- With a project selected in Solution Explorer, Right click on the Project menu ans select Properties.
- Click the Debug tab.
- Select the Use remote machine check box.
- In the Use remote machine field, enter the name of the remote machine, using the format `\\domain\machinename`.